# Sum previous two months sales using Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I've scenario, I need to calculate sum of sales of previous 2 months if I select any month. That is, my months are in parameter and if I select any month I should be able to sum previous 2 months sales.

Comment: Can you provide more detail? What's the level of detail in your view?

Comment: I believe you're looking for a [Window Sum](http://breaking-bi.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/working-with-window-calculations-and.html).  How this specifically applies to your case depends, as mentioned above, on the level of detail of your view.

Answer (score 0):

Add Integer aliases to your parameter (e.g. September stands for 9)

Use calculation: SUM(IIF(DATE_PART('month', [datetime]) = [parameter] - 1 OR DATE_PART('month', [datetime]) = [parameter] - 2, [Sales], 0)

Comment: this calculation isn't helping me to achieve for what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

[WINDOW_SUM()](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_tablecalculation.html) will allow you to sum the previous two months.  Combine that with your parameter to get a dynamic sum of the two months previous to the selected month.

> WINDOW_SUM(expression, [start, end])
>
> Returns the sum of the expression within the window. The window is
> defined by means of offsets from the current row. Use FIRST()+n and
> LAST()-n for offsets from the first or last row in the partition. If
> the start and end are omitted, the entire partition is used.

**Example:**

Let's say you have a parameter `Choose Month` of type integer that allows a user to select a month.  I'm going to assume the data set is limited to the current year, and that your viz is partitioned on Month.

```
WINDOW_SUM(SUM(Sales), -2, [Choose Month])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Parameter "Month_Paramater"
2. Choose Integer --> list
3. add list of values (e.g. 1 as January, 2 as February ..... so on till 12 as December)
4. Create a calculated field :
5. Use calculation:

   `SUM(IIF(DATE_PART('month', [Order Date]) = [Month_Paramater] - 1 OR DATE_PART('month', [Order Date]) = [Month_Paramater] - 2, [Sales], 0))`